# Setting a value to a 2D array/multidimensional matrix with a random index leading into random changes

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, random

I'm very new to C# and I'm having trouble with using a random integer as index for a 2D array. I'm trying to understand what is happening, why is it happening and how to avoid it and ways to solve it.

I'm trying to randomly modify some of the values in the 2D array to another specific string, and after the first change, it looks like everything is fine, but when I go for the second random change, the first modification changes position and I need it to don't change after it has already been selected. Here's an example of the original code that results the same problem:

```
using System;
                        
public class Program
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a;
    string[,] mat = new string[3,3] {{"1","2","3"}, {"4","5","6"}, {"7","8","9"}};
    
    public void Main()
    {
        while (someCondition)
        {
            a = r.Next(0,9);
            if (mat[a/3, a%3] != "x") //Want to change only if it is a new place and have no problem with this part
            {
                mat[a/3, a%3] = "x";
            }
            foreach(var item in mat)
            {
                Console.Write(item);  //Just so I can see the changes
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();     //And to wait for me
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, let's say that it changed the "4" to an "x", so the printing stays *"123x56789"* and when it goes on to change the second time, something happens that not only there's a chance the "4" gets back but it was also a different number all along, so if it chooses "7" for the second go, it prints something like *"123456x8x"* meaning that instead of "4" it was a "9".

I don't get why the "4" doesn't just stay "x" and why it changes to another number and how it recovers the "4" so it can print it normally again (also, for the sake of the example, assume that the second random number is always different than the first, I have ways to check and avoid that in the original code). I want to have something like this

```
//generates the first random and it's a 3 so it prints "12x456789"
//then generates the second random and it's a 7 so it prints "12x456x89"
//generates another random and it's a 2 so it prints "1xx456x89"
//in other words, I don't want to lose the places I already changed
```

I thought that maybe it was because I was changing the value with mat[a/3, a%3] = "x", but I used .SetValue("x", a/3m a%3) and same results. I also thought to maybe just store the value of the randomly generated **int a** into another variable so I did *int b = a* and maybe break the link between something but mat[b/3, b%3] = "x" leads to the same problem.

I also tried to brute force it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (mat[i,j] == a.ToString())
        {
            mat[i,j] = "x";
        }
    }
}
```

thinking that maybe using the random integer just for a comparison would lead to a success, but it ultimately failed.

I didn't find anything that talked about a problem like this or maybe I just don't know how to search for something so specific like that, but I would love to solve it. Just to be clear, this isn't the full original code, just the part that is causing the trouble in a nicer, smaller, more readable snippet with the exact same problem. I did it like this on Python, so that's why I'm trying to do something similar on C#, but maybe it's not even possible and if that is the case, I would like to know why and how to solve it so I can avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: I've run your program - everything is fine and it works just as you want. Are you sure you've posted the exact code?

Comment: As far as I can see the code both looks correct and runs correct. You are not doing anything like re-creating your `Program` object?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact code that was not working, and after reading both comments, I've decided to test the same code on another online debugger/compiler and voilà, it worked. It makes me very angry to not have thought about trying it somewhere else instead of trying many different ways, confident that it was just that I didn't know enough, but it was the IDE messing up, something I didn't even realize it was possible. That's a new IDE for me and thanks for the reply!
PS: since I can't download VS for now because of size, I'm using online compilers to learn right now! Accepting suggestions!

Comment: For further clarification, I was using dotnetfiddle before and now I'm using OnlineGDB